# Ferrite bead resonance

Tags: resonance, oscillation, ferrite-bead

I have checked a reference design because I use the same microcontroller for my thesis.
The PLL power input is filtered by a ferrite bead and a capacitor. I have simulated the circuit and I found that there is a strong resonance at 300kHz.
I assume the reference board is functional so I don't understand how this can't be a problem. Do you know why this is not a problem?
[image: Reference design]

[image: Transient]

Comment: Reference boards are for a particular layout and stackup. A reference design is not guaranteed to work exactly as is, if you change anything from the original design.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly ? Is it your simulation or your real world measurements ?

Comment: There are some documents which mentions these problems. The problem is a 3.3V rail is pushed by 6V voltage. Plus if there is any noise source on the board which causes some spikes on 300kHz then it is amplified on the resonance frequency. (so this filter is garbage on 300kHz) Actually it is worse on 300kHz than if it wouldn't there at all.

Comment: You feel that these documents which describe your problem are not worth posting for someone to answer your question, about why this is happening ? no ?

Comment: Sorry I wanted but I pushed the enter acidentally. http://www.ipblox.com/pubs/Ferrite_beads/Understanding%20Ferrite%20Beads%20and%20Applications.pdf

Comment: Your model of the ferrite is very crude.  Additionally, does the voltage rail slew rate reflect reality?

Comment: Does a real measurement show the same resonance? What effect does changing the capacitance (C214) have? There is usually no downside to improving the decoupling on an analog or PLL supply.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got any measurements right now. The model is not bad in my opinion it gives back the impedance curve in the datasheet. The saturation is not modeled however and maybe the very high frequency behavior is different too but this is a low frequency phenomenon. Maybe we can agree in that ferrite beads are inductors on low frequency and if it is the case a resonance frequency might occur if the dampening is not right.
140uF capacitor removes the ringing but it is huge.Also a 10uF capacitor series with 1 Ohm resistor parallel to 100nF cap removes resonance too.(dominant pole)

Comment: Reference design are never perfect, and some aren't very good at all. If you can make your design better than the reference design, then you should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, resonance of capacitance and ferrite beads can be a problem. They're pretty high Q inductors at low frequencies, which can come as an unpleasant surprise if there is something floating around to ring them up.

You can try to improve things by increasing the capacitance to several uF so the series resistance adds damping or adding some parallel damping resistance, or a bigger ceramic cap + series resistor from VddPLL to ground.

You have assumed the PLL Vdd acts as a high impedance, which may be pessimistic, but I suspect not totally unreasonable.

Comment: To prevent resonance of a bead having series resistance R and inductance L, R must be at least sqrt(4*L/C), where C is the capacitance on the side of the bead opposite the signal source.

Comment: @user96037 Corresponding to a damping ratio of 1.0 (critical damping). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator)

Comment: [This article](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html) may help somehow